# Need advice on using Wireshark + aircrack-ng

Tags: security, wifi

I am making acquiantance with wireless security and attacks and was told to run some tests with aircrack-ng and wireshark.

So I installed both of them and ran airmon to switch wi-fi card to monitor mode:

`sudo airmon-ng start ra0` (this is my DWA-140 usb wi-fi adapter) The wi-fi adapter seems to have restarted after that. Gues that's ok. Still it gave some warnings on processes that might interfere with normal work like `network manager, dhclient` and a few more. I tried to stop them, but they seem to restart all the time.

After that I ran wireshark as a superuser, chose the ra0 adapter and tried to sniff the test open network. I have my PC connected to it (via dwa-140) and an HTC phone and some stranger PCs. Wireshark runs on my PC.

The problem is that when I login to `%sitename%` with a PC browser, I can see the cookies sent to it in Wireshark. But when I do the same thing with an Opera Mobile browser on my HTC (`Turbo` option disabled), there is nothing detected. I know that stranger PCs are also sending data to `%sitename%`, but I see nothing from them as well. Actually I see a lot of packets from stranger PCs, but not the ones I need.

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong. Will be thankful for any advice.

P.S. This runs on Ubuntu 12.04.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by installing an rt2800usb driver. Now monitor mode can be enabled, though sometimes the connection is lost.

Answer (score 0):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mini): Opera Mini requests web pages through Opera Software's servers, which process and compress them before sending them to the mobile phone, speeding up transfer by two to three times and dramatically reducing the amount of data transferred, chargeable on many mobile phone data plans. The pre-processing increases compatibility with web pages not designed for mobile phones.

Perhaps this caching, processing and resending is making the cookies look like a different type of packet. The connection between opera and the proxy server is encrypted, so you will have a lot of difficulty trying to recover plain text cookies by sniffing.

Comment: Actually it's Opera Mobile and the `Turbo` oprion is disabled, so there should be no compression there. Anyway, how about other PCs that use regular browsers? I don't se anything from them either. Still I see cookies sent from my own browser.